# Magento 2.3 - static-content (JS assets ) give 404 some times on production

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, cache

I have **Magento CE 2.3** on production mode the my store running **OK**
but some times some JS  & jQuery gives 404 and the website request in-existing assets from pub/static which causes the whole website to stop.

I found many answers suggesting to switch to Production mode which my store is already in Production mode.

and to switch Symlink to COPY
in `app/etc/di.xml`

```
 <virtualType name="developerMaterialization" type="Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Factory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

which I already did

the problem goes away if I flush the cache and enable it again after running
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US ar_SA`
how can I fix of even debug this issue it is very critical

this is the log in side `myProject/var/log/exception.log`

```
main.CRITICAL: Path  var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/ cannot be used with directory  var/view_preprocessed/pub/static
 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\ValidatorException(code: 0): Path var/view_preprocessed/pub/static
cannot be used with directory var/view_preprocessed/pub/static at vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/PathValidator.php:63)"} []
```

Comment: please check this link https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/magento/A/question/64802.html i hope it will be helpfull in your case.

Comment: my store already in production and assets already in COPY mode not in SYMLINK mode

Comment: Please, post your js errors.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I updated my question with log from exception.log

Comment: how to be sure the project in production


 php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
Current application mode: production. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)